# cannot find class, numerous libraries, composer php5.5

Tags: php, composer-php, static-libraries

I am trying different libraries via composer and on all of them I hit a similar error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyRestApi\Admin' not found in /usr/home/www/tmp/index.php on line 6
```

I have tried short and long path names:

```
set_include_path('/usr/home/www/vendor/marcj/php-rest-service/RestService');
require_once('/usr/home/www/vendor/marcj/php-rest-service/RestService/Server.php');
```

I have tried require, include, require_once, set_include_path.
Also I have tried

```
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
and
require "/home/www/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Always the same error trying to find the first class.

This particular library https://github.com/marcj/php-rest-service it the one I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you get a composer library to work without an autoload? (I am assuming this has something to do with my issue)

You don't. Using the autoloader of Composer is one of the central contracts that every package that gets installed with Composer relies on.

In theory you could try to invent your own autoloading. In practice: Why?

Your code is missing a `require "vendor/autoload.php";` - the path to vendor depends on where your file is that wants to include the autoloader.

Note that if you add your own package and install it via Composer, it must not include the autoloader by itself - the code that uses this package is supposed to do it.

Comment: I forgot to post that I had tried require "/home/www/vendor/autoload.php";  and require "../vendor/autoload.php";   It finds the file but not the class

Comment: Well, your example code "doesn't work fine". It throws a fatal PHP error, because `echo "boo";` is in the middle of nowhere. Can you please create an example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I suppose that code fails because you haven't added your own class to the composer autoloading. What is your `composer.json` looking like?

Comment: Note that `MyRestApi\Admin` is your OWN class, and if you don't take steps to make the code known at the place where it is used, it will fail. Using Composer's autoloading would be the easiest way, but alternatively you still could `require "MyRestApi/Admin.php":` instead. That would work^W trigger the next code error in your index.php...

Comment: I am aware of that. the code in Admin.php is 'their' sample code to put into the MyRestApi/ directory, and their code, like many others with test classes, fail the same way.  So 'no', I have not added my own code, I am using their test code. composer.json  ->  http://paste.ee/p/dhpE1   I know I am doing something st00pid, I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: "They" don't provide any example files that you fill with your code. The examples are guidelines on how to make use of the library, assuming that you know how to make PHP code work in general. The topic of how to load PHP classes is omitted because it is considered basic knowledge and would distract from the topic of the example.

Comment: If you copy/paste and it spits out an error that means it's broke. No clue. I'll try another.